# How to make card-deck align horizontally across page

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, razor-pages

Hello Stack Overflow & Devs,
I'm trying to figure out how to get the card-deck class to align horizontally instead of vertically. Currently have tried several bootstrap options. Hoping to get some info and insight on what I'm doing wrong and code that would possible accomplish this? I'm currently building an ASP.NET MVC5 application. Thank you!

Current Vertical Example:
[image]

```
@model IEnumerable<Employee>

@{ 
    ViewBag.Title = "Employee List";
}

<div class="card-deck">
    @foreach (var employee in Model)
    {
        <div class="card m-3">
            <div class="card-header">
                <h3>@employee.Name</h3>
            </div>
            <img class="card-img-top" src="~/images/naval-warfare.jpg" />
            <div class="card-footer text-center">
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">View</a>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Edit</a>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</a>
             </div>
         </div>
    }
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Added this line of code to get the results I was looking for.

Fixed Example:

[image]

```
@model IEnumerable<Employee>

@{ 
    ViewBag.Title = "Employee List";
}

<div class="col d-flex justify-content-center">
    @foreach (var employee in Model)
    {
        <div class="card m-3">
            <div class="card-header">
                <h3>@employee.Name</h3>
            </div>
            <img class="card-img-top" src="~/images/naval-warfare.jpg" />
            <div class="card-footer text-center">
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">View</a>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Edit</a>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</a>
             </div>
         </div>
    }
</div>
```